# java keytool jks to bks

Tags: java, keytool, jks

I'm trying convert jks certificate to bks but show the next exception:

Problem importing entry for alias myalias: java.security.KeyStoreException: java.io.IOException: Error initialising store of key store: java.security.Invalid KeyException: Illegal key size.
Entry for alias novipemapp not imported.
Do you want to quit the import process? [no]:

Command:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore c:\teste\keystore.jks -destkeystore c:\teste\keystore.bks -deststoretype BKS -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

IOExceptions are often caused by insufficient rights under Windows. Run your cmd as administrator and this should work.